# does map key have an address that I can point to?

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

Can I treat map key as pointer?
I have a struct which member is vector of strings, and I have a map

Is it possible to fill my vector with pointers to string1 ?

example

```
struct A
{
   vector<string> v;
}
map<string, string> m;
m["hello"] = "test";
m["world"] = "test2";

A test;
for(map<string, string>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); it++)
test.v.push_back(it->first)
```

can I do this?

Comment: You're not treating anything as a pointer here. You're just iterating a map and adding its keys to a vector. You're actually operating with strings as values. No pointers anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does map key have an address that I can point to?

Yes, like all objects it has an address.

> Can I treat map key as pointer?

No, it's not a pointer. But you can take its address.

> Is it possible to fill my vector with pointers to string1 ?

No, because it's a vector of strings, not pointers; so you can fill it with copies of the map keys (as your code does), but not pointers. You could have a vector of pointers:

```
vector<string const *> v;
```

and fill that with pointers to the map keys:

```
test.v.push_back(&it->first);
```

If you remove any keys from the map, then make sure you don't try to use that pointer afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

In a way, yes.

If you have a key stored somewhere, or read as input, then you can use it to search the map to see if if the key exists and get its value.

Comment: if I am pointing to key how do I get its value? I thought i could only get both as pair